# How to generate dynamic drop down lists using jQuery and jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a list of type A, in which each element contains another list of type B. I want to create a form in which when a user selects a value from the drop down list containing values of A, another drop down to populate values based on selected item's list of Type B. I am new to jQuery but I know that it is convenient to do this using jQuery rather than pure jsp. Please give me a rough outline of steps that I need to follow to get this done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSP is just a server side view technology. It doesn't compete with jQuery. You can perfectly keep using JSP for this. But I understand that you want to fire an asynchronous request using ajaxical techniques rather than a synchronous request. That's no problem in JSP as well.

First, we need to have two dropdowns in JSP:

```
<select id="dropdown1">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <option value="#{item.value}">#{item.label}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
<select id="dropdown2">
    <option>Please select dropdown1</option>
</select>
```

Then we need to attach some jQuery to the `change` event so that it fills the 2nd dropdown based on the value of the 1st dropdown. Add the following to the `<script>` in JSP or an external script which is loaded through `<script src>` in JSP:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        var servletUrl = 'dropdown2options?value=' + selectedValue;

        $.getJSON(servletUrl, function(options) {
            var dropdown2 = $('#dropdown2');
            $('>option', dropdown2).remove(); // Clean old options first.
            if (options) {
                $.each(opts, function(key, value) {
                    dropdown2.append($('<option/>').val(key).text(value));
                });
            } else {
                dropdown2.append($('<option/>').text("Please select dropdown1"));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In the servlet behind the `url-pattern` of `/dropdown2options` just return the map of options as [JSON](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)). You can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for this.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String selectedValue = request.getParameter("value");
    Map<String, String> options = optionDAO.find(selectedValue);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(options);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
}
```

That's basically all.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question about [chained selectors here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603539/how-to-make-the-value-of-one-select-box-drive-the-options-of-a-second-select-box/2603632#2603632)... I don't know about jsp, but this jQuery version should give you an idea.